# Reading values from binary file stored in char array with reinterpret_cast (C++)

Tags: c++, binary, reinterpret-cast

I am trying to read in a binary file in a known format. I want to find the most efficient way to extract values from it. My ideas are:

Method 1: Read each value into a new char array then get it into the correct data type. For the first 4 byte positive int, I bitshift the values accordingly and assign to an integer as below.

Method 2: Keep the whole file in a char array, then create pointers to different parts of it. In the code below I am trying to point to these first 4 bytes and use reinterpret_cast to interpret them as an integer when I dereference the variable 'bui'.

But the ouput from this code is:

```
11000000001100000000110000000011
3224374275
00000011000011000011000011000000
51130560
```

My questions are

- why does the endianness get swapped using my method 2 and how do I point to it correctly?
- which method is more efficient? I need all of the file, and the file contains other data types too so I will need to write different methods to interpret them if using method 1. I was assuming I could just define different type pointers if using method 2 without doing extra work!

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main(void){
    unsigned char b[4];
    //ifs.read((char*)b,sizeof(b));
    //let's pretend the following 4 bytes are read in representing the number 3224374275:
    b[0] = 0b11000000;
    b[1] = 0b00110000;
    b[2] = 0b00001100;
    b[3] = 0b00000011;

    //method 1:
    unsigned int a = 0; //4 byte capacity
    a = b[0] << 24 | b[1] << 16 | b[2] << 8 | b[3];
    std::bitset<32> xm1(a);
    std::cout << xm1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    //method 2;
    unsigned int* bui = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(b);
    std::bitset<32> xm2(*bui);
    std::cout << xm2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << *bui << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: File I/O is your biggest performance hit.  I suggest method 1.5, read in blocks of data at a time; not necessarily *all* of the data.  You could also have two threads, one for reading the data, the other for processing the data.

Comment: If you need to squeeze out more performance, you may want to perform the extraction (or building) in parallel (provided more than one core is available).